# Do properties of quantum particles 'exist' before observation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

We understand that quantum particles have properties like 'spin'. And upon observation, the value of this property is determined. Before observation, the value is non-determined and the wave function contains all values.

So my question does the property itself exist before observation? Does 'spin' itself exist?

It seems that Bell's Inequality ruling out realism (if you assume locality), means that even the property 'spin' is non-existent until observation.

Comment: Different people will have different opinions about this, the math (theory) is agnostic about this issue (as far as we know)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> does the property itself exist before observation?

Does the sun exist when it is night?

Your intuition would say "obviously yes, the earth is simply blocking it's light", and pretty much every other reasonable person might agree. However, this is an impossible thing for you as an individual, or even us as a species, to confirm with absolute certainty. Any corroborating evidence (a livestream video from the other side of the world, etc.) could equally be explained by some other deception or nuance or unaccounted illusion that leads you to believe that the sun literally disappears whenever you don't see it.

Obviously this an absurd example, but I use it to illustrate this point: whatever we call our "knowledge" of the world is **always** a model that fits whatever observations we are capable of making.

---

It might seem like I'm avoiding the question, but (to borrow from the WorldBuilding Stack) I think that the framing of the question is flawed. For convenience and sanity, we talk about quantum objects 'having' particular properties like spin or momentum in the same we would talk about a spinning top, but ultimately the fundamental nature of quantum particles remains unknown. There are [various philosophical interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) of what the mathematics of the wave-function means in the real world, but the math itself, and the most up-to-date consensus on the laws of physics, makes no such claims.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what I thought. That the 'nature' of the quantum object is just theoretical at this point. But doesn't Bell's Inequality and also the Leggett-Garg Inequality suggest that the properties (like spin, etc) would also be a part of the 'no hidden variables' violation?

Answer (score 1):

My way of thinking about this is as follows, using the electron as an example:

Because it is an electron, you *know* it has spin, and you know how much spin it should have- but you *don't know* which way the spin vector is pointing.

Interacting with the spin vector via a measurement of some sort trips up the electron and forces it to adopt "up" or "down" at that instant, according to laws of probability that are rolled up into the math.

Comment: But is the property itself, and not just the value, created upon observation?

Comment: @ImTalkingCode The usual way of thinking about it is that the property exits, as nielsen says, but that the specific value is created on observation.

Comment: @ImTalkingCode If the property itself didn't exists, then there would be no operator corresponding to it and no wave function could ever collapse to the specific value in question. At least in the normal formulation of the foundations of QM.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus But doesn't the property being 'existent' (for lack of better word) prior to observation, violate the no realism of Bell and Leggett-Garg inequalities?

Comment: To my knowledge, it does not violate Bell's inequality, because Bell's inequality is only concerned with the a priori existence of specific values not the property itself.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Matteo and maybe I could build a bit in the same direction. I guess my answer would appear ridiculous to some people here, but this is how I understand the wave function and quantum physics:
before measuring the electron has no spin, it is not even a particle. In fact the electron does not exist, it is a wave with negative charge. There is some probability that the charge could be in a certain position in a given time but nothing more than that.
The idea that there are some small metal(matter) blocks floating around a nucleus is an easy way to imagine things but is not the way the things are.